# How to avoid calling content when two tags are partially the same in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am currently trying to display content based on product tags that are assigned to products in Shopify.

This is working ok, but my problem is that I have two tags that contain partially the same tag name, so I am getting both sets of content appearing on the front end.

One tag shows a field that is required "r-[tag-name]" and the other shows the same field but it is not required "[tag-name]".

Obviously I know this is due to the fact that I am using 'contains' so the logic is true for both when either tag is applied, but I have tried using '==' (equals) but it when I do, nothing appears at all :/

What I would like to know is, what do I need to change so that the statement is only true if a tag exists that is exactly the same as the if statement.

I am new to Liquid so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!--Convert the tags into a string by joining them with COMMA-->
{% assign productTags = product.tags | join: ', ' %}
<!--Now Check for the desired tag name-->

{% if productTags contains 'r-custom-name-one' %} 
      
<p class="line-item-property__field">
     <label for="name-one">Name One:</label>
     <input class="required" id="name-one" type="text" name="properties[Name One]">
</p>
{% endif %}
              
{% if productTags contains 'custom-name-one' %} 
<p class="line-item-property__field">
     <label for="name-one">Name One:</label>
     <input id="name-one" type="text" name="properties[Name One]">
</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an exact match to 'custom-name-one' on a tag or are you expecting the tag on the product to be a partial match to 'custom-name-one'?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to change so that the statement is only true if a tag exists that is exactly the same as the if statement

This should do it:

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
  {% if tag == 'r-custom-name-one' %}
    <p class="line-item-property__field">
      <label for="name-one">Name One:</label>
      <input class="required" id="name-one" type="text" name="properties[Name One]">
    </p>
    
    {% break %}
  {% endif %}
  
  {% if tag == 'custom-name-one' %}
    <p class="line-item-property__field">
    <label for="name-one">Name One:</label>
    <input id="name-one" type="text" name="properties[Name One]">
    </p>

    {% break %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I added `{% break %}` which will

> Causes the loop to stop iterating when it encounters the `break` tag.

I assumed that once the tag is found, you don't need need to continue looping through the rest of the tags!